# builtins.AttributeError: 'Pet' object has no attribute 'get_name'

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm currently receiving this error:

> builtins.AttributeError: 'Pet' object has no attribute 'get_name'

It's showing for the line of code `print(item.get_name())` right after the for loop at the end of the program.

Here's my class:

```
class Pet:

    def __init__(self, name, type, age):
        self.__name = name
        self.__type = type
        self.__age = age

        def set_name(self, name):
            self.__name = name

        def set_type(self, type):
            self.__type = type

        def set_age(self, age):
            self.__age = age

        def get_name(self):
            return self.__name

        def get_type(self):
            return self.__type

        def get_age(self):
            return self.__age
```

Here's my program:

```
import pet

def main():

    animals = make_list()

    print('Here is the data you entered:')
    display_list(animals)

def make_list():

    animal_list = []

    print('Enter data for 3 animals.')
    for count in range(1,4):
        print('Pet number '+str(count) + ':')
        name = input('Enter the name: ')
        type = input('Enter the type: ')
        age = input('Enter the age: ')
        print()

        animal = pet.Pet(name, type, age)

        animal_list.append(animal)

    return animal_list

def display_list(animal_list):

    for item in animal_list:
        print(item.get_name())
        print(item.get_type())
        print(item.get_age())
        print()

main()
```

Comment: Place the code in code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` symbol in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of `Pet`'s methods need to start at the same indentation level.  You need to unindent every line from `set_name` through `get_age` by one level each.

Comment: Yes, as it's written, all the other methods are actually functions within the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple that I was just over looking. Thanks again!